# how to import a eclipse code template file to intellij idea?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

There are two different files about code style in eclipse:

1. Code formatter file
2. Code template file.

Now I know the code formatter file can be imported with the path:

```
 "settings -> code style -> import"
```

But I do not know how to import the code template file, and the code template file has the path:

`"settings -> file and code template"` in ***intellij***.

Now I am coding in a project where other people use eclipse, and they only have the eclipse code template file.

Is there a way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot import **code templates** *out of the box*. 
That might change in the future though..
http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/01/intellij-idea-13-importing-code-formatter-settings-from-eclipse/

Your best bet for now is to get this plugin to work and give it a go.. 
https://code.google.com/p/eclipse2idea/ 
http://www.danhaywood.com/2009/10/11/converting-eclipse-templates-to-intellij-idea/

I couldn't find the plugin on the marketplace or an update site for it though.
Best of luck..