# How can I import Emmet snippets into IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, emmet

I usually using Eclipse as default IDE but now I need to migrate to IntelliJ in my work.
I've worked with custom Emmet snippets created by myself in Eclipse, I exported them as an XML file in order to load on IntelliJ, but I was not able to found where to import it.
Do anyone know how to do it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing of Eclipse templates currently is not supported. Only Code Style can be imported. [Here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/01/intellij-idea-13-importing-code-formatter-settings-from-eclipse/) is the post from 2014 in JetBrain's blog regarding that. Current progress could be checked at [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-104068).

Here is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551256/how-to-import-a-eclipse-code-template-file-to-intellij-idea) on StackOverflow.